c++ module operator doesn't work properly
This program should find idiom or odd number:
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    int number,mod;
    bool done = false;
    do{
        cout<<endl <<"Enter a number:"<<endl;
        cin>>number;
        mod = number&2;
        if (number == 0){
            done=true;
        }
        else if (number < 0){
            cout<<"We couldn't say idiom odd";
        }
        else if (mod == 1){
            cout<<"This number is odd";
        }
        else if (mod==0){
            cout<<"This number is idiom";
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Something is wrong.";
        }
    }while(!done);
}

I saw some problems and wrote the last part (something is wrong part), so what's the problem?
I don't have any clue why this happened, and I checked the code for a long time, still I think there is nothing wrong.

Please [edit] your question to provide more details on what you expected to happen versus what actually happened. This will help readers figure out what didn’t work and how to answer your question accordingly.

I have formatted your code. However - your question still lack details. Please take a [tour] and see [ask].

& is bitwise AND. % is the modulo operator. What's a bit funny is that odd-ness can be determined using bitwise AND.

"c++ module operator doesn't work properly" - What is a C++ "module operator"? I see no "modules"..

"I saw some problems" - please [edit] your question to explain what the problems actually are.

Should idiom number be called even?

You almost certainly want the modulo operator: % but if you want to use bitwise operators, you could AND with 1. This will let you determine if that bit is set or not. If it is, the number is odd.

"I think there is nothing wrong." I believe this is an example of Dunning-Kruger. Someone with little knowledge of a topic believes themselves to know more about it than they do. Obviously something is wrong (you wouldn't have asked a question otherwise). And the chances of it being compiler or operating system bug for something as basic as modulo arithmetic instead of an issue with your code is practically 0.

How is this question closed? Once it was edited to present the code in a readable format, the issue at hand immediately presents itself? What more details are needed?

@sweenish Q is closes because it's unclear what problem OP is solving. "what's the problem?" is not a good question because see the first sentence and unclear expectations.

The First Rule of Programming: It's Always Your Fault seems relevant.

@3CxEZiVlQ Is it actually unclear, though? SO users are notorious for refusing use context clues. And this is clearly a toy program or homework assignment for detecting whether a number is even or odd. Comments getting hung up on typos and demonstrating a lack of any critical thinking are the worse problem than this question.

Change mod = number&2; to mod = number % 2;
You are using the bitwise AND operator, and not the modulo operator. Bitwise AND compares the actual 1s and 0s that make up the integer. The result will be that when both bits in the same position of the numbers being compared are 1, the same bit in the result will be 1, otherwise 0. A number being even or odd is determined by the last bit. If that bit is 1, the number is odd. If it's 0, the number is even.
You could use the bitwise AND operator if you wanted to. std::cout << (number & 1 ? "Odd" : "Even") << '\n'; also works. The & 1 will zero out all bits except the last one, if the number is odd. The result would then be 1, which is true. An even number will create a 0 result, which is false.

I upvoted, but you might improve this by explaining why number & 1 actually does work.

val & 1 also works for negative integers (unlike % operator which might return -1 instead of 1), Example: -1 is 0xFFFF'FFFF, last bit is 1.

@prapin I ran a sample and got my expected values mixed up. I've corrected that mistake and added explanation that was requested.
